# EEVEE rendering with a weird 'pixel effect'

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have a problem wtih the new version (2.81): EEVEE renders wtih a weird 'pixel effect' on meshes. Even when i render the image i get this effect. I don't know where's the problem. I've already tried to reinstall it but it doesn't change. Does anybody know how to solve it?

[image: EEVEE 'pixel effect']

[image: EEVEE 'pixels' on meshes]

Comment: What is your node setup for the cube?

Comment: Looks like an issue with your graphics driver. Try to update it and check if that resolved the issue. What is your CPU and GPU?

Comment: I haven't got a GPU

Comment: The node setup is the default one

Comment: try activating screen space reflections it some how fixed the problem for me

Comment: You need to have a GPU otherwise you couldn't run Blender (or display anything on your monitor). Your CPU likely has an integrated GPU. Please open the `dxdiag` program and check what GPU is listed in the *Display* tab. Verify whether or not your GPU meets the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.8x. If it does, try to find updated drivers for your GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off shadow, go to light then click off shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Intergrated GPUs have limited support (especially on AMD / vega it seems).

This is a bug for which the only fix is a driver update or switching device.